# Save order of JQuery UI droppables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I currently have a basic Jquery UI droppable shopping cart based off the example given:
http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart

My question is how do I essentially convert the items that have been dragged into the shopping cart to a post'able form that saves the items in the shopping cart, and the order they are in.

I looked into searlizing the shopping cart items, and place it into a hidden form element but I can't seem to serialize the list.

Any help/suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best way to go about it, but I've always populated hidden input fields for this. I'm guessing you probably know how to  go about coding that, but I can help if needed.

```
// On drop of the items or onsubmit of form
// Create a <input type="hidden" id="id of your item" />
// Post that instead
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use input type hidden fields to contain the dropped items and submit. For this, you need to write a bit of jquery code to copy the dropped items content into hidden field value in a format expected by the web server.

The format can be something like comma separated or json string or any other.